# Anchor Javascript Window Reloading

Tags: javascript

all ready link here : `site.com/en/#gone_videoid`

new url :

```
var url = 'en/#gone_videoid2';
window.location.href= url;
```

coming url : `site.com/en/#gone_videoid2`

but window refeshing when refering location href
i want work like this click

```
<a href="en/#gone_videoid2">video</a>
```

this clickig not refeshing window

Comment: Maybe you want `window.location.href = '#gone_videoid2;'`... I have difficulties do understand what your problem is, sorry.

Comment: When you change the URL it has to refresh the page... unless you change it to just `#gone_videoid2` in which case it'll take you to an anchor with that id on the same page... (or your JS can pick it up and do work)

Comment: if you click <a href="en/#gone_videoid2">video</a> this the browser appending #gone_video2 in url without refreshing window .... my question this : HOW we do this . window.location.href="en/#gone_videoid2"; if we do this. the browser refreshing

Comment: Also look at [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history)

Comment: window.history not answer for this problem

Answer (score 1):

use `window.location.hash` instead of `window.location.href`:

```
window.location.hash = "#gone_videoid2"
```

will only update the hashtag of the current URL

Comment: i know this but its url being : site.com/en/#gone_videoid1#gone_videoid2

Comment: appending last of url without refreshing . i need to like this but we must clear " en/ " last from url  and add new Params

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href=newUrl
```

no refreshing window